# jQuery executes codeparts in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, electron

I'm currently working on a project for my uncle, who is a vet. It's an electron project, that lets him manage his clients, patients and their visits. However, after some time in use, we realised, that sometimes the ipcRenderer fires twice, or even more times, when trying to insert a new client, patient or appointment. I've tried to catch this by adding another sql query, that checks if an identical record, to what i want to insert is already in the database. Now though, whenever I try to insert a new record, the db.all() (was a db.run() at first, I've been trying to fix by trial and error for the last few hours and got desperate) which inserts the record is executed before the db.all(), that gets the number of identical records and sets the counter, although it should be executed after. I've tried to fix this with $.when() and .done(), but then had the problem of not being able to check, if the counter is 0, because .done() expects a function and .done(if) doesn't work. I'm more of a C++, java, C# guy btw and not really that familiar with jQuery, JS and what so ever, so sorry if my mistake is trivial.
Here's the code, you can ignore these long ass SQL statements, I know, they're not according to coding conventions, but they work:

```
$("#btn-ins-patient").on("click", function() {
        ipcRenderer.once('insert-patient', function(event, arg) {
                        
            let checksql = "select count(*) as 'zaehl' from patient where "
            + "owner = " + arg.owner + " and name = '" + arg.name + "' and species = '" + arg.species + "' and breed = '" + arg.breed + "' and sex = '" + arg.sex + "' and neutered = '" + arg.neutered + "' and dead = '" + arg.dead + "' and chipnr = '" + arg.chipnr + "' and birthdate = '" + arg.birthdate + "'  and color = '" + arg.color + "';"

            db.all(checksql, function(error, rows) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.code, checksql)
                    insertpatsql = "select * from patient where id = 1;";
                }
                else{
                    console.log(checksql);                      //second output in console, prints the right statement
                    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var counter = rows[i].zaehl;
                        console.log(counter);                   //third output in console, prints 0
                        setCount(counter);
                        console.log(cnter);                     //fourth output in console, prints 0 again
                    }
                    if(cnter != 0){
                        insertpatsql = "select * from patient where id = 1;";
                        console.log(insertpatsql);
                        console.log("double entry was stopped");
                    }
                    else{
                        
                        console.log(insertpatsql);              // fifth output in console prints the right statement (insert)

                    }
                    
                }  
            });

            let insertpatsql = "insert into patient"
            + "(owner, name, species, breed, sex, neutered, dead, chipnr, birthdate, color, notes, diverse)"
            + "values ('" + arg.owner + "', '" + arg.name + "', '" + arg.species + "', '" + arg.breed + "', '" + arg.sex + "', '" + arg.neutered + "', '" + arg.dead + "', '" + arg.chipnr + "', '" + arg.birthdate + "', '" + arg.color + "', '" + arg.notes + "', '" + arg.diverse + "');";

            if(cnter == 0){
                db.all(insertpatsql, function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error.code, insertpatsql)
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(insertpatsql);
                        loadPatients();
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                console.log("double entry was tried", insertpatsql, cnter);
                                                              //first output in console, cnter is undefined
            }
        })

        let child = new BrowserWindow({
            height: 485,
            width: 795,
            parent: parent,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            show: false,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
        })

        child.loadFile('./ins/patient.html')

        child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
            child.show()
        })

        child.on('closed', () => {
            child = null
        })
    })
```

The `select * from patient where id = 1;` is just for security reasons, because, the second db.all() was sometimes executed, even though it should not have been. I know my code is messy, I'm sorry, I've been trying to fix this all day ....

This is how i set the cnter (global variable):

```
var cnter;

function setCount(cnt){
    cnter = cnt;
}
```

How do I ensure, that checksql and its codeblock get executed before the insert?

Comment: you mean the first request is not finished and the second request begins?

Comment: yes basically. I don't understand how or why this happens. the first db.all() and the if(cnter == 0) would have to start almost simultaneously. why doesn't it work all through the first block, before starting the other one? or does it just start the second one at first?

Comment: db.all is not async?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understan all!!, but this is the schema to chain database transactions

```
function onSomeButtonClick()
{
  // The first query callback
  var firstQueryResults;
  var firstQuery = function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(
      'SELECT * FROM databaseName WHERE greeting = "hello world"',
      [],
      function(tx, results) {
        firstQueryResults = results;
        return nextQuery(tx);
      });
  };

  var nextQuery = function(tx) {
    // Prepare something using firstQueryResults
    tx.executeSql('SOMETHING ELSE HERE',
      [],
      function(tx, results) {
        // Something good happens here
        return true; // Be sure to return false to roll back
      });
  };

  database.transaction(firstQuery, null, nextTransaction);
}

function nextTransaction() {
  // The next full transaction that's dependent on the
  // first transaction's data is called AFTER the first
  // transaction has completed.
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I get the alert, but except for that everything else stayed the same. Sorry, if i worded my question weirdly, i'll try to summarise the problem: sometimes when I tried to insert a record, this record would be inserted twice. I looked around and found out, that this has something to do with the ipcRenderer executing more than once. I've tried to catch this with the checksql, but now, the second db.all() gets executed before the first block is finished, which makes the first one basically useless, because the code relies on the checksql filling the cnter before inserting.

Comment: the alert doesnt end the process, so you could initialise a setInterval to wait the right value of checksql

Comment: i read db.all is async, so you could use .then() to execute next action

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fixed it, by putting the second block inside the first one. This is the Code as it is now:

```
$("#btn-ins-patient").on("click", function() {
        ipcRenderer.once('insert-patient', function(event, arg) {
                        
            let checksql = "select count(*) as 'zaehl' from patient where "
            + "owner = " + arg.owner + " and name = '" + arg.name + "' and species = '" + arg.species + "' and breed = '" + arg.breed + "' and sex = '" + arg.sex + "' and neutered = '" + arg.neutered + "' and dead = '" + arg.dead + "' and chipnr = '" + arg.chipnr + "' and birthdate = '" + arg.birthdate + "'  and color = '" + arg.color + "';"

            let insertpatsql = "insert into patient"
            + "(owner, name, species, breed, sex, neutered, dead, chipnr, birthdate, color, notes, diverse)"
            + "values ('" + arg.owner + "', '" + arg.name + "', '" + arg.species + "', '" + arg.breed + "', '" + arg.sex + "', '" + arg.neutered + "', '" + arg.dead + "', '" + arg.chipnr + "', '" + arg.birthdate + "', '" + arg.color + "', '" + arg.notes + "', '" + arg.diverse + "');";


            db.all(checksql, function(error, rows) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.code, checksql)
                    insertpatsql = "select * from patient where id = 1;";
                }
                else{
                    console.log(checksql); //first output in console
                    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var counter = rows[i].zaehl;
                        console.log(counter); //second output in console
                        setCount(counter);
                        console.log(cnter); //third output in console
                    }
                    if(cnter != 0){
                        insertpatsql = "select * from patient where id = 1;";
                        console.log(insertpatsql);
                        console.log("double entry was stopped");
                    }
                    else{
                        
                        if(cnter == 0){
                            db.all(insertpatsql, function(error) {
                                if (error) {
                                    console.log(error.code, insertpatsql)
                                }
                                else{
                                    console.log(insertpatsql);
                                    loadPatients();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("double entry was tried", insertpatsql, cnter); //fourth output in console, cnter is undefinded
                        }

                    }
                    
                }  
            });
            
        })
})
```

I won't know, if it actually works until the ipcRenderer tries to fire twice again though. As soon as I have confirmation that it works, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the issue is that you register an event handler inside an event handler. In most cases, event handlers should be registered once at the global scope, not within another event handler.

I wasn't understanding all the things you were doing with that counter, but I think you're trying to do this:

```
ipcRenderer.on('insert-patient', function(event, arg) {
                
    let insertpatsql = "insert into patient"
    + "(owner, name, species, breed, sex, neutered, dead, chipnr, birthdate, color, notes, diverse)"
    + "values ('" + arg.owner + "', '" + arg.name + "', '" + arg.species + "', '" + arg.breed + "', '" + arg.sex + "', '" + arg.neutered + "', '" + arg.dead + "', '" + arg.chipnr + "', '" + arg.birthdate + "', '" + arg.color + "', '" + arg.notes + "', '" + arg.diverse + "');";

    db.all(insertpatsql, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.code, insertpatsql)
        }
        else{
            console.log(insertpatsql);
            loadPatients();
        }
    });
})

$("#btn-ins-patient").on("click", function() {

    let child = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 485,
        width: 795,
        parent: parent,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    child.loadFile('./ins/patient.html')

    child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        child.show()
    })

    child.on('closed', () => {
        child = null
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I know the counter is a little bit confusing, but i had to define it as a global variable and make a set-function, otherwise i wouldn't have been able to access it in the second scope. I had it inside the function at one point, but then it didn't set it, so I made it global. In hindsight that was probably because the codeblocks were executed in the wrong order, so I see why it's confusing. I'm also not the best at coding in general, and tend to not reverse the unnecessary edits I made when looking for an error when I'm trying different approaches ...